Как разрешить ввод в поле input только цифр, и только средствами PHP?
Как разрешить пользователю в поле <input type="text" вводить только цифры? Интересует решение только средствами PHP. Как это сделать с помощью атрибута pattern я знаю. Как это сделать с помощью JavaScript или JQuery я тоже знаю. Но как это сделать только средствами PHP, и возможно ли такое?

эм... в PHP нужно сделать проверку, что клиент отправил корректные данные... для клиента есть JS, CSS, теги и тд) это все клиента, оно его и принадлежит ему. Из PHP контролировать действия на стороне клиента, звучит как бред) но все же.. можно повесить обработчик, который будет постоянно общаться с сервером (php) и корректировать поведение клиента...

Только средствами PHP вы не сможете это сделать. Можно проверить только уже введенные данные на строне сервера, которые пришли с клиента и вернуть результат.
В PHP функция ctype_digit(), которая проверяет, содержит ли значение только цифры.
// $inputValue - значение полученное с клиента
if (ctype_digit($inputValue)) {
    // Если значение состоит только из цифр
} else {
    // Если введенное значение не состоит только из цифр
}

А если хотите проверять прямо при вводе, то без JS это сделать не получится. Потому что РНР выполняется на сервере, а форма - в браузере у пользователя.

Ну так себе решение... И не указано, как значение с клиента, силами только PHP, должно приходить на сервер и как отправляется ответ с перерисовкой данных на клиенте.

@SwaD в принципе, если есть проверки на жс, то перерисовывать ничего не надо, достаточно швырнуть 400

@Ипатьев судя по вопросу и ответу, на js нет проверок, а значит на каждый введенный символ, клиент, должен пулять сообщение php скрипту, ждать ответа и возможно перерисовывать введенные данные. Если быстро вводить, то ответы могут прийти не в той последовательности, что были отправлены. А если это будут 100 клиентов, то и сервак можно приложить... я бы такого делать не стал. На сервере, конечно проверка нужна, но уже при финальной отправке данных.

Здесь соглашусь, дергать сервер на каждый введенный символ - это глупость
